# Where is my PATH env. var being redefined?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path

Since a couple of days ago my Ubuntu 12.04 installation is presenting some strange behavior, due to auto update probably, as I've not messing with any config:
1 - The system default encoding changed from UTF-8 to ANSI_X3.4-1968 - I've never heard of such encoding :[
2 - Typing 'ifconfig' resulted in "The command could not be located because '/sbin' is not included in the PATH"

I tried to set-up locale configurations by many means, with no success, then I concluded that the wrong PATH settings could be the cause.
I've probed all the files where PATH could be set, and still couldn't find where it chages:

```
user@pc~> grep PATH /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
user@pc~> grep PATH /etc/bash.bashrc
user@pc~> grep PATH /etc/profile
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.bash
grep: /home/likewise-open/user/.bash: No such file or directory
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.bashrc
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.pam_environment
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.profile
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.bash_profile
grep: /home/likewise-open/user/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
user@pc~> grep PATH ~/.bash_login
grep: /home/likewise-open/user/.bash_login: No such file or directory
user@pc~> echo $PATH
/home/likewise-open/user/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Some how my company-imposed likewise-open puts itself in the PATH, and the proper locations are removed, but where? Any tips?

Comment: Try `grep PATH= ~/.* /etc/*`. If that doesn't help, `grep -RI PATH= ~ /etc`.

Comment: Bear in mind that `/sbin` is normally not in normal users' paths, only in root's. In any case, all you need to do is define your path in your `.bashrc` and add `/sbin` to it.

Comment: @terdon: I don't know about other distributions, but `/sbin` is in every user's default path on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Dennis "Normally, these directories are never part of normal user's $PATHs, only of roots" http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/sbin.html.

Comment: grepping didn't showed me where the path is being broken, so I just added the missing entries to my ~/.profile - my language settings are still invalid though.
changing locale settings by GUI crashes the accounts-daemon - and by CLI nothing has effect - but that's another topic.

Comment: thanks Dennis and terdon, I'll leave the question open for a while, to see if other ideas come up. About the locale stuff, it may not be related at all: DBusException: org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.Failed: running '/usr/share/language-tools/save-to-pam-env' failed: no output